# Combining hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2019

I was on Politics just now, and noticed [this user](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/27044/surprisedog):

[image: Two hats?]

On my screen, it appears that they are wearing both Where in the World? and Warm Welcome at the same time.  When I try to equip hats, however, there seems to be a one-per-user limit for use of them.

What's up here? **Is this a glitch, or is there a way to equip two hats that I just don't understand?**

Comment: Oh I figured it out...not posting a self answer because it'll get downvoted. The secret is that [their profile picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srffn.png) includes the hat.

Comment: Answer to the question linked above both explains that multiple hats are not possible and how users can appear to wear more than one.

Comment: If you wanted to know more about my fabulous hat collection, you could have just asked me ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no spoon. And only one hat.

[image]

Actual display pic

[image]

behatted doggo.

And your instinct was correct - its one hat, no matter the number of heads, and you can't combine them without cheating..

It appears someone did you the bamboozle

Comment: "*no matter the number of heads*" - hat tip to your chatty canine chat competitor?

Comment: Well, sure :D. The whole answer *is* 99% canine humour...